# (Pandas, Python) Selecting indices of a parent DF based on shared column values with a child DF

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

(I recently asked this question on r/learnpython ([here](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/uifnc5/pandas_selecting_indices_of_a_parent_df_based_on/)), but didn't get any feedback, so am re-posting it verbatim here.  Hope that is okay!)

Suppose I have a DataFrame **Y** that looks like this:

​

| *index* | *x1* | *x2* | *A* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 5 |
| 1 | 3 | 7 | 1 |

And then I have a parent DataFrame **X** like this:

​

| *index* | *x1* | *x2* | *A* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | 0 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 | 0 |
| 3 | 3 | 7 | 0 |

Further, suppose that any `['x1','x2']` combination that exists is unique (so any combination exists in either **X** or **Y** only 0 or 1 times, and if it exists in **Y**, then that particular `['x1','x2']` combination (although the `'A'` value may be different) exists in **X** as well).

For all `['x1','x2']` combinations in **Y**, I would like to find the corresponding indices in **X**.  So here, those indices would be a list `[0,3]` that I want.

My goal is, for all such rows in **X** with such an index (I'll call it `j` here), to set

`X['A'].loc[j] = Y['A'].iloc[j]`

Currently I have this:

```
for i in range(len(X)):
    v1 = X['x1'].iloc[i]
    v2 = X['x2'].iloc[i]
    extract = Y.query("x1 == %d" % v1).query("x2 == %d" % v2)
    if len(extract_ori) != 0:
        X['count'].loc[i] = extract['count'].iloc[0]
```

​

This does what I want, except it is pretty slow, and it seems like there should be a faster way to do this.  Wondering what this might be, if it exists!

​

So the resulting DataFrame **X** should look like

​

| *index* | *x1* | *x2* | *A* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 5 |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | 0 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 | 0 |
| 3 | 3 | 7 | 1 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use `MultiIndex.map`:

```py
cols = ['x1','x2']
X['A'] = X.set_index(cols).index.map(Y.set_index(cols)['A']).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Another option is left-merge on two columns:

```py
cols = ['x1','x2']
X = X[cols].merge(Y[cols+['A']], on=cols, how='left').fillna(0)
```

Output:

```py
   index  x1  x2  A
0      0   1   2  5
1      1   1   3  0
2      2   3   4  0
3      3   3   7  1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could `set_index` the x1 and x2 column and update the dataframe on the `A` column.

```
X1 = X.set_index(['x1', 'x2'])
Y1 = Y.set_index(['x1', 'x2'])

X1['A'].update(Y1['A']) # works inplace
X1.reset_index(inplace=True)
print(X1)

    x1  x2  index   A
0    1   2      0   5
1    1   3      1   0
2    3   4      2   0
3    3   7      3   1
```

**UPDATE**
the shorter version:

```
X.set_index(['x1','x2'], inplace=True)
X.update(Y.set_index(['x1','x2']))
X.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Comment: This worked for me!  I am giving the answer to the other, as I had to make less new dataframes, but this was helpful!

Comment: Totally fine. It is just another option here. I edited my answer to show you it is possible with less variables (did it for convenience)